# What is the logic behind type conversion when comparing wrapper classes and primitives with == operator?

Tags: java, wrapper, autoboxing, type-promotion

I read that compiler refuses to use auto boxing/unboxing when there is more than one operation needed in order to perform implicit conversion (`int -> double -> Double` or `Integer -> int -> double`). It's stil rather confusing

```
Integer i = 2;
Double d = 2.0;
System.out.println(i == d); // COMPILE TIME ERROR

// fix

System.out.println( (double) i == d); // OK: true
```

My understanding is that the compiler tries to unwrap `i` with `Integer.intValue()`. Since it takes more than one step to convert Integer to double (`Integer` -> `int` -> `double`) compiler refuses to do it implicitly, so we need to "help him" by using explicit type conversion, which will reduce the number of steps. Is it correct?

```
Integer i = 2;
double d = 2.0;
System.out.println(i == d); // OK: true
```

In this example it clearly takes more than one step for the compiler to perform conversion (`Integer -> int -> double`). How come it doesn't complain?

*I'm aware that one must use `equals()` method over `==`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), in section [15.21. Equality Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21):

> The operators == (equal to) and != (not equal to) are called the equality operators.

Section [15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) says:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)).

Section [15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) says:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are `null`).**

Without a cast, the `i == d` expression must follow the rules in section 15.21.3, because both `i` and `d` are *reference types*, not *numeric types*. Only the primitive types are *numeric types* (except `boolean` of course).

Since an `Integer` cannot be cast to a `Double`, and a `Double` cannot be cast to an `Integer`, the compiler knows that it is impossible for the expression to be true (ignoring the case where both values are `null`), so a compile-type error occurs.

When you do `(double) i == d`, then the left-hand side becomes a numeric type, and the rules specified in section 15.21.1 applies.